# Blogging Infrastructure using Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, wordpress, blogs

I'm researching the prospect of incorporating a blog into my site. Currently, my site is written using the Zend Framework so it's not just a case of using Wordpress and that be the end of it.

I was wondering. Has someone already done what I'm thinking of doing and written a blog infrastructure with comments and so forth using ZF?

Anyone got any suggestions?

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of a ready to download blog module that you can add to an existing ZF project, but virtually every tutorial in ZF is setting up a Blog.

Check out

- [Survive The Deep End - Chapter 8: Developing a Blogging Application](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/developing.a.blogging.application)

Comment: Judging from the lack of replies and the response from Gordon there's not much out there and it's more of "going it alone".

Cheers, I think my question has been answered.